# variable is not working in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using following in my shell script

```
LOGDATE='date +%m%d%y_%H%M'
```

and then calling same as following in the same shell script

```
$LOGDATE
```

but it is printing output as following

```
echo $LOGDATE

date +%m%d%y_%H%M
```

could anyone tell what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `LOGDATE="$(date +%m%d%y_%H%M)"`

Comment: Are you trying to store the command `date +%m%d%y_%H%M` in the variable `LOGDATE`, or are you trying to execute the command and store its output in `LOGDATE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've mistaken single quote character `'`, used for escaping strings (no variable is expanded, backslash doesn't escape character, and delimiters are ignored) for backtick character `` ` `` that executes the content in a subshell and returns stdout as a string.

```
LOGDATE=`date +%m%d%y_%H%M`
```

Newer bash versions also allow the syntax

```
LOGDATE=$(date +%m%d%y_%H%M)
```

It may be considered more readable and allows for easier nesting of expressions: